# .htaccess redirection for subdomain exception

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htacccess file below. Any request for http://domain.com is redirected to http://www.domain.com except for the subdomain 'support' which is accessed at http://support.domain.com. How do I make this exception? Also I want https://support.domain.com redirected to http://support.domain.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/?$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-=_?]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

Answer (score 0):

**Insert this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^support\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```